# logstash not parsing all messages

Tags: json, logstash, logstash-grok

im trying to parse syslog messages with logstash
im using grok match :

```
    "message", "\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}\] \[%{WORD:module}\] \[%{LOGLEVEL:severity}\] (\[tid=%{DATA
:tid}(\s)?\]) (\[%{DATA:auth}:%{NUMBER:linenum}:%{DATA:method}\]) %{GREEDYDATA:data}"
```

and i'm getting this error message:

[logstash.filters.json    ] Error parsing json {:source=>"message", :raw=>"[2017-03-27 09:18:03,071] [WS-Server] [INFO] [WebSocketsHandler:81:on_message] [ON_MESSAGE] [140609651632016] [trn_id: 1062fed9-9ae3-4523-8817-657031e83af1] Received update-device-details message from box 38:b8:eb:50:00:a9", :exception=>#

what im missing ?

thanks

Comment: http://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/match#result You can use this app to test your grok pattern against your log lines.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely because this:

```
[2017-03-27 09:18:03,071] [WS-Server] [INFO] [WebSocketsHandler:81:on_message] [ON_MESSAGE] [140609651632016] [trn_id: 1062fed9-9ae3-4523-8817-657031e83af1] Received update-device-details message from box 38:b8:eb:50:00:a9
```

Is not valid JSON. Your hint is this in the error:

```
[logstash.filters.json ] Error parsing json
```

That tells me there is a `json {}` filter being applied to this in addition to the `grok {}` segment you've quoted. I suggest you review your `filter { }` statements and figure out how the raw syslog message (very likely still the `message` field) is ending up getting parsed by a `json {}` filter. Grok has nothing to do with this.